# PosgreSQL - ERROR: relation "table_name" does not exist. How to query without schema name?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-migration

I am migrating from oracle to postgreSQL.
In my application I have a lot of queries like this

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT NAME FROM Table_name");
```

But I am failing with exception

> ERROR: relation "table_name" does not exist.

As far as I understood I need also provide schema name, and when I am performing like this, it works:

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT NAME FROM schema_name.Table_name");
```

So basically my question is - How could I avoid refactor all queries?

Comment: Maybe the table was created as "Table_name", not: table_name ? (when double-quoted, case matters!)

Comment: No, table name is correct

Comment: Adjust your [schema search path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command, as mentioned above, will set search path for current session

```
SET search_path TO schema_name,public;
```

However if there is need to do it for all session, just correct config file - pgsql/11/data/**postgresql.conf** add search path

```
search_path = '"$user", YOUR_SCHEMA'
```

Restart the DB.

Answer (score 1):

You want to put the tables in Postgres into the `public` schema (the default) or use a search path.

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/ddl-schemas.html) explains this.

Answer (score 1):

`searchpath` defines the order and list of schemas to be search for unqualified names. By default it is `"$user", public` so first user schema and then `public` is looked to.

You can change this order via:

```
SET search_path TO schema_name,public;
```

More details on this are [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH).

You can configure this after connection is open for example.

Alternatively you can set this for user once:

```
ALTER ROLE username SET search_path = schema_name,public;
```